# Windows cannot start booting

Tags: linux, windows, boot, windows-10, grub

Yesterday I downloaded Windows 10 .iso file from DreamSpark. I installed it and I noticed my laptop cannot start windows booting. It gets stuck in the reboot loop. My BIOS loads then I get black screen for few seconds and my computer restarts.

When I plug flash drive with Windows installer I get 'Press any key...'. If I don't press any key my system starts normal.

I've tried 'bootrec /fixmbr', 'bootrec /fixboot'. I've also tried reinstall from another .iso. I've also tried to use 'repair my computer' but Windows couldn't do this.

Previous I've had Linux Debian and GRUB.

```
Where was windows installed?: SSD, C: partition
Where was boot loader installed?: I have no idea, I think on that same partition on which system.
What happens when you start machine with Windows installer USB plugged in?: I see "Press any key...". If I don't press any key, Windows 10 boots and works fine.
What do you mean by "system starts normally". : Windows 10 boots and works fine.
Have you been able to start into windows 10 at least once using any method since the installation?: Yes, I have. I've described it above.
Have you tried using GRUB to boot windows?: No.
```

Comment: I do understand that the situation you found yourself in is frustrating, but can you please provide a more detailed description of the problem (at least provide HW specs of the machine you are installing windows on). Also can you please explain what are you trying to achieve now? Do you still want to install windows 10 or are you trying to revert to Debian?

Comment: How can I fix it? Now I have windows 10 and I want to stay on it. I'd like to fix problem with booting.

Comment: You can provide more infos e.g. as @ArtGertner mentioned

Comment: To receive help from other users, please expand your questions as much as possible. Please provide following info: basic Hardware setup of the machine. Main external storage setup (HDD volumes, partitions, etc). Where was windows installed? Where was boot loader installed? What happens when you start machine with Windows installer USB plugged in? What do you mean by "system starts normally". Have you been able to start into windows 10 at least once using any method since the installation? Have you tried using GRUB to boot windows?Please answer all these questions by editing your original post.

Comment: I have Samsung RV720-02 laptop. i3-2310m, gtx 520m, 4gb ram, 128gb SSD, 500gb HDD. 3 months ago I had Windows 10 and it was working well. Yesterday I had two system, Windows 8.1 + Debian and I was using GRUB. I've decided to come back to Windows 10 so I've downloaded Windows 10 .iso file from DreamSpark. I burned it on pendrive by using Rufus. I've formatted all partitions and I've runed installation. Everything was going well. Unfortunately when I power on my laptop BIOS is loading, then I got black screen for 2 seconds and restart. It does everytime. @Art. I'll answer you in few minutes.

Comment: @Art I've edited original post.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info. I have posted the answer below. Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1):

OP did not provide much info, but from what I can gather from the original question, the problem originates from the bootloader. My recommendation would be the following:

First, attempt to boot into windows using any available method:

- Use USB with GRUB loader to auto-detect windows and boot into it
- Use Windows installed USB to load into windows

When booted into the system execute the following command with admin rights, replacing **drive_letter** with the letter of the drive where windows is installed (most commonly C)

`bootsect /nt60 drive_letter: /mbr`

This should fix the boot record of the specified partition and the MBR of the relevant disk.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've solved my problem by removing my second disk before installation. I don't know how it helped but everything is ok. Anyway I'm thankful for your answers.

Answer (score -1):

Probably the windows.iso your trying to boot contains some errors or it might be some faulty version.

Try booting your USB using rufus.exe named software and then first plug in your usb and then try to restart.